# SQL Server - Generate the same random number into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I would like to generate a random number (5 or 6 digits) but not just into one column, in 4 actually.

```
    ID1     ID2      Type           LotNumber        ID3     ID4
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    721     721       1                Lot1          721     721          
    721     721       1                Lot1          721     721
```

Looking over the internet and several articles, mostly generate a random number to be used in just one column and that's it. Is there any way I can achieve this using SQL? Thanks

**EDIT**

I used this statement:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(99999-10000+1)+1000) AS ID
```

**VIEW**

```
CREATE VIEW MyView

AS

SELECT 
'' AS ID1,
'' AS ID2,
CASE WHEN t.fADTableField4Code='Aggregated' THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(2 AS BIT) END AS Type,
ISNULL(t.fADTableField3Code, '') AS LotNumber,
'' AS ID3,
'' AS ID4

FROM MyTable AS t


GO
```

**XML File**

The XML file has to look like this:

```
<Documents>
  <Document>
   <ID1>721</ID1>
   <ID2>721</ID2>
   <Type>1</Type>
   <LotNumber>Lot1</LotNumber>
   <ID3>721</ID3>
   <Date>2018-12-04</Date>
   <Details>
     <Detail>
     <ID4>721</ID4>
    ............
   </Details>
</Document>
```

Comment: Use a sub-query

Comment: Don't have any idea how it should look.

Comment: Show us how you would create a single random number and we can assist with using it multiple times.

Comment: I edited the post @DaleBurrell.

Comment: And you want to use the same random number for multiple rows as well as multiple columns? Or do you want a new random number for each row? And how is the rest of the row data generated e.g. Type, LotNumber?

Comment: I have a view. Within the view, i have all the columns mentioned in the post and the values from LotNumber and Type are static information and I can extract from a specific table.

Comment: And yes, for each ID column and in each row should be the same random number.

Comment: Show us the view. At this point anybody on this end is guessing.

Comment: I would ask though, what is the point of having four columns with the same data.

Comment: I need to send some information within an XML file of multiple sales orders, that have different unique codes within the database, that has to go under the same ID.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need the same value in multiple columns. Why can't you simply put a random value in ID1 and be done with it? And not sure how putting random values in a column in a view is a great idea anyway. Every time you look at the data those values will change.

Comment: Do you want the same random value for each each column AND the same value on each row? That is what your stated output looks like.

Comment: @SeanLange - yes.

Comment: @srkkk you do realise that putting a random number in a view means it will be different every time you query the view?

Comment: This screams of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps if you share what you are really trying to accomplish we can help you find a solution. But four columns of random numbers across every row in a view is absurd.

Comment: @Dale - i understand. That was my approach at this moment but it can be changed according to the need. I edited my post of how the XML file should look like.

Comment: Can you also explain what these random ID fields are actually used for? Because as it stands they change every time you generate the XML, and have no way of being linked back to the original order... so what is their purpose?

Comment: How are you generating the XML file? Since the ID values are the same across the whole dataset seems like changing the XML generation would be a LOT simpler.

Comment: The XML file will be imported into another system and this identifier is required.

Comment: @SeanLange - i use the `FOR XML` clause.

Comment: Best of luck, I am out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and expand upon it.

```
select a.*
    , b.id as ID1, b.id as ID2 --Get ID from applied table and use as often as you need
from (select 1) as a(ID) -- this is your main table
cross apply (SELECT FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(99999-10000+1)+1000) AS ID) B
```

Comment: This gets a random value for the columns in one row, but the OP quite strangely wants the same random value for each column AND each row. >.< This code will generate a new random value for each row.

Comment: I thought that's what he wanted. for every row and column I would suggest a variable instead of a subquery

Comment: Hence the absurdity of this question. It also has to be a view, so no variables. Still this gets a +1 from me because it is the closest to a sensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either a CTE or a subquery

```
SELECT 
    ID1 = R.ID
    ,ID2 = R.ID
    ,ID3 = R.ID
    ,ID4 = R.ID
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(99999-10000+1)+1000) 
        AS ID
    ) R


;WITH R
AS
    (SELECT 
        FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(99999-10000+1)+1000) 
        AS ID
    )
SELECT 
    ID1 = R.ID
    ,ID2 = R.ID
    ,ID3 = R.ID
    ,ID4 = R.ID
FROM R
```